# Fragment onCreateView is being called two times android

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am using viewPage, FragmentManager and Fragment. there is a switch case in FragmentManager to initialize each fragment. But my fragment's onCreateView is being called two time for the first time my app comes in foreground. I am attaching FragmentManager class along with fragment's onCreateView method code. Please tell me whether I am doing anything wrong.

below is my fragmentManager class

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {

        case 0:
            //Home fragment activity
            System.out.println("fragment case 0");
            return new LatestFragment();
        case 1:
            // Pages fragment activity
            System.out.println("fragment case 1");
            return new MostDownloadFragment();
        case 2:
            // Photos fragment activity
            System.out.println("fragment case 2");
            return new BestFragment();
        case 3:
            // WhatsHot fragment activity
            System.out.println("fragment case 3");
            return new FavouriteFragment();

        default:
            break;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 4;
    }
}
```

and below is onCreateView of fragment

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_latest, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);


        context=getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        adapter = new ImageAdapter();

        if (TabsArraylistData.al_latest.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("fragment latest if");
            new GetCategoryAsynTask().execute();
        }else {
            System.out.println("fragment latest else");
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        return rootView;
    } // onCreateView -----------------------------------------------------
```

my problem is that System.out.println("fragment latest if"); is being printed twice

Comment: Is `fragment case 0` (or whatever number is) also printed twice? Is there any other code which calls `new WhateverFragment()`?

Comment: fragment case 0 and fragment case 1 are getting printed simultaneously and both are getting printed only once

Comment: Which of the fragments does problematic `onCreateView` belong to? How many times are the methods `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`, `onDestroyView` of that fragment called?

Comment: LatestFragment and mostDownloaded are problematic and only onCreateView is being called twice other are only once